# Can I execute untrusted Common Lisp code in a restricted environment?

Tags: common-lisp, dsl

Supposed I wanted to take advantage of Common Lisp's ability to read and execute Common Lisp code so that my program can execute external code written in Lisp,  but I don't trust that code so I don't want it to have access the full power of Common Lisp.  Is it possible for me to restricts its environment so that it can only see the packages/symbols to which I explicitly give it access, effectively creating a DSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the code, start by disabling `*read-eval*` (that stops people injecting execution during parsing, using something like `#.(do-evil-stuff)`. You probably want to do the reading using a custom read-table that disables most (if not all) read-macros. You probably want to do the reading with a custom, one-off, package, importing only symbols you allow.

Once you've read the user-provided code, you still need to validate that there's no unexpected function/macro references in the code. If you have used a custom package, you should be able to confirm that each symbol falls in either of the two classes "belongs to the custom one-off package" (this is user-supplied stuff) or "explicitly allowed from elsewhere" (you would need this list to construct the custom package).

Once that's been done, you can then evaluate it.

However, doing this correctly would take a fair bit of care and you really should have someone else have a look at the code and actively try to break out of the sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the section 'Reader security' in [chapter 4 of Let over lambda](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html) which discusses this topic in some depth. In particular, you probably want to set `*read-eval*` to `nil`. To address your question regarding restricting access to the environment, this is generally difficult in Common Lisp, as it is designed to allow access to most pieces of the system in the first place. Maybe you can use elaborate the ideas of Let over lambda in the direction of white listing symbols (in comparison to the blacklisting of macro characters in the linked chapter). I don't think there are any ready-made solutions.